# Asp.net Webapi using [FromUri] with Route that has two parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

```
   [Route("Street/{ZoneID}/{StreetID}/")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetStreet(int ZoneID,int StreetID,[FromUri]       RealEstateFilter Filter)
```

StreetID Is Always 0 when Following Request Is Being Sent From Client

> http://localhost:1887/Street/34/23295?MunZone=7&StartDate=&EndDate=

but it works without any optional parameter

> http://localhost:1887/Street/34/23295

how should i configure webapi to be able to read [Fromuri]

Comment: i also tried  [Route("Street/{ZoneID}/{StreetID}")]

Comment: Can you post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? This is working OK for me, I've made some assumptions about `RealEstateFilter` which I've posted below. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `Street/34/23295?MunZone=7&StartDate=&EndDate=` with my Controller Defined as:

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Street/{ZoneID}/{StreetID}/")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetStreet(int ZoneID, int StreetID, [FromUri] RealEstateFilter Filter)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Gave:

[image]

When I defined RealEstateFilter as:

```
public class RealEstateFilter
{
    public int? MunZone { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

My web.api version is:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net451" developmentDependency="true" />
```

I created my Web.Api project from scratch, and this is the only thing in it. Is it possible you have some other route that is interfering?

Comment: <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" /> not interfering with other route
 because it hits the breakpoint in controller.

Comment: Can you share a more complete example. e.g. on github?

Comment: Thank you NikolaiDante . i found the problem , the query String had a parameter StreetID at end of string  so it was Always binding to StreetID in route rather than StreetID in url.my query string was Street/34/23295?MunZone=7&StartDate=&EndDate=&StreetID=, i removed StreetID form querystring. sorry to take your time and thanks for your answer.